# not getting response data in completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession

i am using this code to make request to server . i got the responce in  completionHandler block then i want to pass in succes block but i got null

```
-(void)getJsonResponse : (NSString *)urlStr success : (void (^)(NSDictionary *responseDict))success failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSLog(@"error====%@",error);

        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"str is %@",str);

        // Convert to JSON object:
        NSError *jsonerror = nil;
        NSData *data1 = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsondistionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:&jsonerror];
        NSLog(@"str is JSON ERROR %@",jsonerror);

        NSLog(@"%@", jsondistionary); here i am getting data 
        success(jsondistionary) ;
    }]resume];  
}
```

this i my call method here i want to get response but getting null

```
[self getJsonResponse:SERVER_API_URL success:^(NSDictionary *responseDict) {

        NSLog(@"%@ responseDict ====",responseDict);
        /here i am getting null 

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        // error handling here ...
    }];
```

what is wrong in method

Comment: use Advance Rest Client and see what you got there might be issue with webservice side

Comment: stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding to your URL string

Comment: as a quick test log your SERVER_API_URL and copy paste that url in the browser, see if you have any valid responses.

Comment: if you are getting data in jsondictionary then why are you passing it to success?

Comment: from response i am getting data  but my NSLog(@"%@", jsondistionary); here i am getting data 
        success(jsondistionary) ; not able to pass data that is issue

Comment: Is all of this code built with ARC?  If not, you probably need to retain the dictionary.  If so... are you certain that you're not looking at the results of two different requests?

Answer (score 0):

First verify if you are getting valid JSON response from the URL you are trying to make request(Using some REST client eg: POSTMAN). After that, skip the step where you are converting to string and then again converting to data(data1). Directly use the data you are getting in the completion block to get the Dictionary.

```
 -(void)getJsonResponse : (NSString *)urlStr success : (void (^)(NSDictionary *responseDict))success failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSLog(@"error====%@",error);


        NSDictionary *jsondistionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonerror];
        NSLog(@"str is JSON ERROR %@",jsonerror);

        NSLog(@"%@", jsondistionary);
        success(jsondistionary) ;
    }]resume];


}
```

Comment: from response i am getting data  but my NSLog(@"%@", jsondistionary); here i am getting data 
        success(jsondistionary) ; not able to pass data that is issue what is wrong in block

Comment: Not sure...use of completion block looks fine to me. Can you still try what I had mentioned in my answer, just to make sure that creation of dictionary is proper and let me know